# SKProductsRequest to add a button the title containing in-app purchase price

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have and appdelegate requesting AppStore products details during the init method, and I want to display the price of an in-app purchase product into a button inside a popover.

I have already setup the request that returns the product array correctly, and the strings containing the prices. My problem is that the popover view controller creates the view before the AppStore reply, and the title label is initialized with (null). If I could delay the button title set I would have been sure that the request did got replied, but that makes the App crash.

My request is

```
- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData {
NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:@"com.thePrintLabs.product"];
productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
productsRequest.delegate = self;
[productsRequest start];
```

}

then I read the reply with:

```
NSArray *products = response.products;
proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products firstObject] retain] : nil;
if (proUpgradeProduct)
{
NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);


NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
priceWeek = [NSString stringWithString:[formatter stringFromNumber:proUpgradeProduct.price]];
}
```

in the popOverViewController I'm doing this to set the button title:

```
myAppDelegate *delegate = (myAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(button1Week:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
NSString *priceWeekly = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Weekly %@",delegate.priceWeekly];
[button setTitle:priceWeekly forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

My button always initialize with (null). Can I update the button after the request was successful?

Comment: is it possible your button shows _before_ the response comes back from the server?

Comment: yes, that's the main problem

Comment: in that case you should just refresh/show the button _after_ you get the response from the server.

Comment: are you thinking about a notification sent to the object creating the buttons sent over after the reply to productsRequest?

Comment: I have normally created a whole class which implements the all features of `SKStoreKit.framework` and it communicates the caller via completion blocks, but the notifications are the same good, of course.